# How to get the closest character that is greater than the given one in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, locale, string-comparison

I need to get the closest character specific to locale that is greater than (in terms of string comparison) the given one in postgresql. I tried to use

```
SELECT chr(ascii(x)+1);
```

But when I test it, it doesn't work sometimes in the way I want, for

```
SELECT chr(ascii('я')+1);
```

returns ѐ, but

```
SELECT 'я' < 'ѐ';
```

returns FALSE.

Comment: Is я ASCII?  I'm fairly sure that it's not.

Comment: 'ascii' function must return unicode number of non-ascii characters, according to the specification

Comment: "ASCII code of the first character of the argument. For UTF8 returns the Unicode code point of the character. For other multibyte encodings, the argument must be an ASCII character."  For UTF8 that's true.  Is your data UTF8?  If so, I should have read the docs first :).  (Though, arguably, Postres should logically name their function.)

Answer (score 1):

Sort order of text depends on `lc_collate`, not on the ASCII code or Unicode code point.
These happen to go hand in hand with basic ASCII characters in most locales. The rest may vary.

What's your output of `show lc_collate`?

The behaviour you are expecting only works with locale `C`. Read all about it [in the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html):

> The C and POSIX collations both specify "traditional C" behavior, in
>   which only the ASCII letters "A" through "Z" are treated as letters,
>   and **sorting is done strictly by character code byte values**.

Emphasis mine. PostgreSQL 9.1 has a couple of new features for collation.

Comment: lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij: there you have your answer. I don't know from the top of my head, how to get the next character specific to the locale. The Docs may provide information.

Comment: So is it impossible just to get the next character that will be greater than the given one if it is not in locale C? o_O Update: pardon, didn't see your comment...

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij: it is definitely possible somehow, I just don't know.

Comment: By the way, my postgresql gives me a syntax error when I try the examples from the tutorial with the COLLATE keyword. My version is 8.4.

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij: you notice the **9.1** in my answer and in the link? :)

Answer (score 0):

In locales other than C/POSIX, this is in general not possible without an exhaustive search.  You had better reconsider your requirement.

If you are only dealing with a limited problem space in practice, such as Russian or Latin alphabets, I suggest you put an explicit letter list somewhere in your application.  But if you need this working for arbitrary Unicode characters or strings, you're going to have some issues.